# htaccess not working - update image path with cookie value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using this in my htaccees to alter an img path depending on a cookie value:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # check for client cookie   
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (?:^|;\s*)client=([^;]*)
    # check if an image was requested   
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$
    # exclude these folders
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !some/members/logos  

    # grab everything before the variable folder and everything afterwards
    # replace this with first bracket/cookie_value/second bracket
    RewriteRule (^.+)/VARIABLE/(.+)$ $1/%1/$2 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Image links are like so:

```
<img src="http://www.some.com/images/VARIABLE/img/1.jpg" alt="" />
```

I'm happy I made it this far, but the problem is... it doesn't work. And I don't know why? Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks!

**HALFWAY:**
I got this to work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/VARIABLE/(.+)$ $1/SET_VALUE/$2 [L]
```

Which replaces my variable with a set_value. However as soon as I add a single Condition, the whole thing fails and no images show up whatsoever. For example this should give me the cookie value, which I want to enter instead of SET_VALUE:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} (?:^|;\s*)client=([^;]*) [NC]
```

Comment: If you have full control over your Apache, then enable debug mode: `RewriteLogLevel 9` (or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging for latest versions) and check the logs -- it should tell you in details where it fails (the more higher debug level the more verbose/detailed log will be).

Comment: don't have access... :-( Any other idea where to get some info on whats happening? I'm just guessing-uploading-checking right now, which I don't want to see myself doing for very much longer...

Comment: Maybe you can local Apache then? Otherwise it may be try-and-try-again in circle. In any case: `^(.+)/VARIABLE/(.+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$` pattern for RewriteRule will get rid of 2nd condition. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/some/members/logos` should work fine as well (unless you have wrong path here!!).

Comment: I would suggest checking those `%{xxx}` variables as well -- maybe they have different values to what you expecting, for example: `RewriteRule ^info$ /debug.php?uri=%{REQUEST_URI}&cookie=%{HTTP_COOKIE} [L]` and then check in that debug.php what those variables will contain.

Comment: cookie left, rest seems to work

Comment: @LazyOne: got it... I forgot to add the ";" when setting the cookie... half a day for a semi-colon... nice ;-) If you want to post your stuff as answer, I will check and upvote. A big thanks for some really good pointers. If I get stuck with htaccess again, I will know whome to look for ;-)

Comment: I'm glad you've sorted it out. In any case: hint is still a hint -- not a complete answer. But now you know -- use "debug" approach when facing the problem and to test your patterns on real/actual data and not only "theoretical" ("how I'm expecting it to be") data samples. Good luck with the rest :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** (after much meddling and a lot of help from @LazyOne!):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   # exclude these folders
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/some/members/logos  
   # check for client cookie        
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} client=([^;]*) [NC]       
   # replace variable with cookie value
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/variabel/(.+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$ $1/%1/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The tricky part, which took forever to solve is to make sure your cookie has a trailing semi-colon... I had my cookie set like this:

```
   document.cookie = "client=value"
```

Which did not work. Changing it to this:

```
   document.cookie = "client=value;"
```

made it work. Maybe helpful for someone eles, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the problem is that you wind up with a path like `/images/jpg/1.jpg` or `/images//1.jpg`?

You're using `%1` as a backreference to your cookie value, but the backreferences should refer to the "last matched RewriteCond", and you have others (including one with a grouping) after the one you want to match. Try moving the cookie one to last.

In addition, you have two groupings in that cookie one, but you're using `%1`, which would end up referring to `(?:^|;\s*)` instead of `([^;]*)`, which would give you the wrong results.

If that's not your problem, can you elaborate on how the URL is coming out? Is it not getting rewritten at all, or is it being rewritten wrongly?

Comment: Thx for the info. It's not being written at all.

Comment: I thought if I group before and after my variable I could then do (group before)/cookie/(group after) and get back the original URL parts

Comment: If it's not being rewritten at all, then there must be another problem. I can't see it at a glance, so I'd suggest removing `RewriteCond`s selectively until you find out which one (or the rule itself) is causing the problem. Maybe temporarily use a string instead of `%1` until you get it rewriting at all.

Comment: Yes, (group before)/cookie/(group after) shouldn't be a problem at all. The RewriteRule wouldn't interfere with the `%1` backreference, just the other RewriteConds.